# Obtain hardware timestamp

Tags: networking, timestamp, libpcap, ioctl, timeval

Is the time obtained by the pcap_next_ex function in libpcap the hard timestamp of the network card? If not, how to obtain the hard timestamp when the packet is received
pcap_next_ex(pcap_t* p,struct pcap_pkthdr** pkt_header,const u_char** pkt_data)

Answer (score 1):

> Is the time obtained by the pcap_next_ex function in libpcap the hard timestamp of the network card?

Only if the code path that delivers packets *to* libpcap gets a timestamp from the network card and provides it.

Currently, the only operating system on which libpcap provides an *option* to get hardware timestamps on regular network interfaces is Linux, but that's not the default; by default, packets get the standard Linux networking stack time stamp, which is generated by the OS when the packet is processed.

Some specialized devices, where libpcap *doesn't* use the regular networking stack to get packets, *might* provide hardware time stamps.  That might be the case for Endace DAG cards, but I don't know whether that's the case.

> If not, how to obtain the hard timestamp when the packet is received

You will need to use the new [`pcap_create()`](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_create.3pcap.html)/[`pcap_activate()`](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_activate.3pcap.html) API, rather than the old [`pcap_open_live()`](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_open_live.3pcap.html) API, to open the adapter.

After calling `pcap_create()`, call [`pcap_list_tstamp_types()`](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_list_tstamp_types.3pcap.html); it will return a list of [time stamp types](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-tstamp.7.html) supported by the adapter and OS.  *If* either `PCAP_TSTAMP_ADAPTER` or `PCAP_TSTAMP_ADAPTER_UNSYNCED` are available, you will want to make libpcap use one of those.  To do so, use [`pcap_set_tstamp_type()`](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_set_tstamp_type.3pcap.html) to set the time stamp type before calling `pcap_activate()`.

NOTE: the time stamps you get might *not* be represented as seconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC; they might differ from that value by a few seconds (whatever the difference was between TAI and UTC at some point in time - I'd have to check the Precision Time Protocol spec to see what that offset is).  This Is A Bug, and I will try to fix it at some point, *if* there's a way to determine whether adapter-supplied time stamps in Linux are based on the UN*X epoch or on some TAI epoch.